# Invalid number SQL 01722

Tags: sql, oracle

I created this table:

```
create table user_info(
ID number(3) primary key,
employee_id number(6),
login varchar2(8) not null,
password varchar2(16) not null, check (password>5),
creation_date date default sysdate,
constraint empid_fk foreign key(employee_id) references employees(employee_id)
)
```

When I want to insert into some values,

```
insert into user_info values(123,123123,'login','password','08-04-2016');
```

I receive this error:

```
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Can someone explain what is wrong in my insert query?

Comment: Is this an Oracle database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> check (password>5)

Won't work there. Your password is a varchar2, not a number. You can't check if its value is higher than 5, as it is not a number.

If you're trying to check the number of characters in it, you can use :

> password varchar2(16) not null CHECK (LENGTH(password) > 5)

Comment: 00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
I am getting this error, if I am checking how you wrote

Comment: Just edited because of a typo, can you try it this way ?

Comment: LEN 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: Are you using SQL Server, Oracle, or anything else ?

Comment: Try with LENGTH then. Should have asked before, thought you were on SQL Server (that's why giving good tags on question are important :p)

Comment: now I created the table, but still cannot insert into

Comment: 02291. 00000 - "integrity constraint (%s.%s) violated - parent key not found"
*Cause:    A foreign key value has no matching primary key value.
*Action:   Delete the foreign key or add a matching primary key.

Comment: Is there any employee with ID "123123" in your employees table ? That sounds like it's your problem there.

Comment: yeap, after posting the comment i understood that i dont have an employee_id=123123, and changed...now it works, thank you!!!